# Why doesn't the layout work in a modal dialog in Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a simple dialog box with the content laid out in a tabular manner:

- Row 1

  - Column 1: This cell should contain the text `.col-md-4`
  - Column 2: `.col-md-4 .ml-auto`
- Row 2

  - Column 1: `.col-md-3 .ml-auto`
  - Column 2: `.col-md-2 .ml-auto`

I wrote the following [code](https://github.com/dpisarenko/modal-layout-problem/blob/master/app/index.html) for this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML File</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button ng-click="buttonClicked()">Show Modal Dialog</button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">My title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">.col-md-4 .ml-auto</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">.col-md-3 .ml-auto</div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 ml-auto">.col-md-2 .ml-auto</div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- container-fluid -->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- modal-content -->
        </div> <!-- modal-dialog -->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The corresponding [app.js](https://github.com/dpisarenko/modal-layout-problem/blob/master/app/app.js) file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {
    console.log("Init");
    $scope.buttonClicked = function() {
        console.log("Button clicked");
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'
        });
    };

});

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.ok = function () {
        console.log("Closing with OK");
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };

    $ctrl.cancel = function () {
        console.log("Closing with Cancel");
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

When I

- run `npm start`,
- open the `http://localhost:8000` link, and
- press the button `Show Modal Dialog`,

I see every cell in a row (i. e. no tabular structure):

[image: Screenshot]

[Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) (section *Using the grid*) say it should work, but it doesn't.

Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It must be related to the](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) `responsive-breakpoints` you are using. When there is not space enough bootstrap just make that. Use `xs` instead, it must solve the problem (`col-xs-4`).

> xs -> extra small devices
>
> sm -> small devices
>
> md -> medium devices
>
> lg -> large devices
>
> xl -> extra large devices

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 ml-auto">.col-xs-4 .ml-auto</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 ml-auto">.col-xs-3 .ml-auto</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 ml-auto">.col-xs-2 .ml-auto</div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- container-fluid -->
```